# Linux Kernel: manually modify page table entry flags

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, page-tables

I am trying to manually mark a certain memory region of a userspace process as non-cacheable (for educational purposes, not intended to be used in production code) by setting a flag in the respective page table entries.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 (ASLR disabled) with a 4.4 Linux kernel running on an x86_64 Intel Skylake processor.

In my kernel module I have the following function:

```c
/*                                                                                                                      
 * Set memory region [start,end], excluding 'addr', of process with PID 'pid' as uncacheable.                           
 */                                                                                                                     
ssize_t set_uncachable(uint32_t pid, uint64_t start, uint64_t end, uint64_t addr)                                       
{                                                                                                                       
    struct task_struct* ts = NULL;                                                                                      
    struct vm_area_struct *curr, *first = NULL;                                                                         
    struct mm_struct* mm;                                                                                               
    pgd_t * pgd;                                                                                                        
    pte_t * pte;                                                                                                        
    uint64_t numpages, curr_addr;                                                                                       
    uint32_t level, j, i = 0;                                                                                           

    printk(KERN_INFO "set_unacheable called\n");                                                                        

    ts = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID); //find task from PID                                                    
    pgd = ts->mm->pgd; //page table root of the task                                                                    

    first = ts->mm->mmap;                                                                                               
    curr = first;                                                                                                       
    if(first == NULL)                                                                                                   
        return -1;                                                                                                      

    do                                                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                   
        printk(KERN_INFO "Region %3u [0x%016llx - 0x%016llx]", i, curr->vm_start, curr->vm_end);                        

        numpages = (curr->vm_end - curr->vm_start) / PAGE_SIZE; //PAGE_SIZE is 4K for now                               
        if(curr->vm_start > curr->vm_end)                                                                               
            numpages = 0;                                                                                               

        for(j = 0; j < numpages; j++)                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                               
            curr_addr = curr->vm_start + (PAGE_SIZE*j);                                                                 
            pte = lookup_address_in_pgd(pgd, curr_addr, &level);                                                        

            if((pte != NULL) && (level == 1))                                                                           
            {                                                                                                           
                printk(KERN_INFO "PTE for 0x%016x - 0x%016x (level %u)\n", curr_addr, pte->pte, level);                 
                if(curr_addr >= start && curr_addr < end && curr_addr != addr)                                             
                {                                                                                                          
                    //setting page entry to PAT#3                                                                          
                    pte->pte |= PWT_BIT | PCD_BIT;                                                                         
                    pte->pte &= ~PAT_BIT;                                                                               
                    printk(KERN_INFO "PTE for 0x%016x - 0x%016x (level %u) -- UPDATED\n", curr_addr, pte->pte, level);  
                }                                                                                                         
            }                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                 

        curr = curr->vm_next;                                                                                             
        if(curr == NULL)                                                                                                  
            return -1;                                                                                                    

        i++;                                                                                                              
    } while (curr != first);                                                                                              


    return 0;                                                                                                              
}
```

To test the above code I run an application that allocates a certain region in memory:

```c
//#define BUF_ADDR_START 0x0000000008400000LL    /* works */                                                         
#define BUF_ADDR_START 0x00007ffff0000000LL      /* does not work */

[...]

buffer = mmap((void *)BUF_ADDR, BUF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED | MAP_POPULATE, 0, 0); 
if ( buffer == MAP_FAILED )                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                   
    printf("Failed to map buffer\n");                                                                               
    exit(-1);                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                   
memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);                                                                                        
printf("Buffer at %p\n", buffer);
```

I want to mark the buffer uncacheable using my kernel module. The code in my kernel module works for 0x8400000, but for 0x7ffff0000000 no page table entry is found (i.e. lookup_address_in_pgd returns NULL). The buffer is definitely allocated in the test program, though.

It seems like my kernel module works for low addresses (code, data, and heap sections), but not for memory mapped at higher addresses (stack, shared libraries, etc.).

Does anyone have an idea why it fails for larger addresses? Suggestions on how to implement set_uncachable more elegantly are welcome as well ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set Page protection to uncached.
Please refer to [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461234/manually-set-nx-bit-of-specific-pte)